# Exception with dll load in jni

Tags: c, dll, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror, javah

I'm trying to implement a simple HelloWorld application with JNI. To call the c function from Java. I created a java class:

```
class HelloWorld{
private native void print();
public static void main(String[] args){
    new HelloWorld().print();


}

static{
    System.load("c://jni_training//HelloWorld.dll");
}
```

}

then generated a .h file, created c implementation and successfuly generated the .dll. But I cannot execute java HelloWorld...I see exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\jni_training\Hello World.dll: Can't find dependent libraries 
   at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1928) 
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825) 
   at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792) 
   at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059) 
   at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:10
```

What the issue?

Comment: Can you paste the error message as text as I cannot read the image

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\jni_training\Hello
World.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1928)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
        at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:10)

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using `System.load` with a hardcoded path instead of `System.loadLibrary` using a predefined library search path?

Comment: no, there is no reason. I doesn't have any specific sense. I've investigated my dll with dependecy walker and noticed that it requires  MSVCR90.dll.... here is the problem....how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, If you know for sure that msvcr90.dll is what is dependency then you can have multiple options.

1. Put the dll in java library path , just do System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));and you know what is the library path, and copy your dll file into one of the directory.
2. load the dll same way you are loading the HelloWorld.dll, 
   Refer : [Nice explanation](http://www.bullraider.com/java/core-java/random-articles/293-unsatisfiedlinkerror-can-t-find-dependent-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

If that DLL is not in C++ then you'll have to interface via a CLI class morphism.